# Python 3.8 error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx

So essentially I'm trying to figure out why a module, called "pyttsx3" is installed, but for some reason in VS code it refuses to run and gives me the error code `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'`, however when I look at my list of installed modules, pyttsx3 is in fact installed? I've been trying to get it to work with this minimal reproducible example taken directly from the git-hub for this python module as an example piece of code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this? It seems rather odd to me that it wont import despite the fact that it is installed?

Comment: Modules for different Python versions are seperated. You have to install it for the interpreter configured in the IDE.

Comment: @KlausD So I just tried that and it said it was already installed, any more thoughts? I also only have python 3.8 installed I believe, however I also installed anaconda so I'm not sure if there are additional versions because of that

Comment: I recommend simply using python 3.6 for any projects involving pyttsx3 because it supports tons of libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with pyttsx3.
I downgraded to Python 3.7, then it worked fine.

Comment: I found that I had an Anaconda environment which was where some packages where heading too! Thank you so much for your help though!